# How to run a script (for version number generation) every time autotools is run

Tags: eclipse, sh, autotools, automake

I am using autotools/eclipse/linux.
I want to run a script to increment the build number in a header file every time I hit the build button. Do I add it in the Makefile.am? What is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this: add it to the `all` target so that it gets run every time, and declare it as `.PHONY` so that make doesn't try to relate it to an existing file.

```
all: update-build-number

.PHONY: update-build-number
update-build-number:
    $(srcdir)/my_increment_script
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Started me on a pursuit which led me to the code below.

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful to others trying to do version control with git and automate their version numbering

Here is my number generator:

```
#!/bin/sh
#echo "Test version of version_script runs OK!"
    majorversion=1
    #echo "Commits"
    #git rev-list HEAD
    lastmerge=`git rev-list --merges HEAD | head -n1`
    #echo "Last Merge"
    #echo $lastmerge
    #echo "Merges (Sub version)"
    #git rev-list --merges HEAD
    subvn=`git rev-list --merges HEAD | wc -l`
    #echo $subvn
    #echo "Commits+1 since last merge (Sub sub version)"
    subsubvn=`git rev-list HEAD | grep -B99999 -e$lastmerge - | wc -l`
    #echo $subsubvn
    #echo "No merges"
    #git rev-list --no-merges HEAD
    #git rev-list --no-merges HEAD | wc -l
    #echo $majorversion.$subvn.$subsubvn > versionnumfile
    echo $majorversion.$subvn.$sub
```

Major version is hard coded (at the moment), sub version is number of merges, sub-sub version is number of commits (+1) since last merge